# Looking for a book about barbarians

Tags: story-identification

My mother told me about a book. It's pretty old. It's about a city that is controlled (I think) which is surrounded by wilderness populated by barbarians. One of the main characters, a woman, decided to go out and explore the wilderness only to be captured by a male barbarian. He takes her with him and she eventually falls in love with him.

Please help...

Comment: How old is "pretty old". Why did she leave the city? What makes this scifi or fantasy?

Comment: Old an in say +- 50 odd years. I have no idea why she left the city. I remember my mother saying that the woman and the rest of the people living in the city are told never to leave the city but she does. Sothing about the city is very controlled or constricted if I remeber correctly. I have not read the book though.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything scifi or fantasy. What about it differed from historical fiction?

Comment: It sounds a little like the post-apocalyptic novel [*The Masters of Solitude,*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Masters-Solitude-Marvin-Kaye/dp/0385124805) by Marvin Kaye and Parke Godwin. It does have a closed high-tech city surrounded by wilderness, and it has a woman that left the city to explore who marries a "barbarian". But the book is set after the city-woman's death and is more about her sons, the culture outside the city, and the events set in motion by her leaving the city.

Comment: If it were a comic book, it would obviously be [Axa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axa_(comics))...